# Unity Void Start does not run multiple times between Updates from different class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a MiniMax algorithm for my chess game. To run the algorithm the game needs to destroy and respawn game objects multiple times between updates. The problem is that the Void Start function only runs the first time I spawn the object. When destroying the object and spawning it again during the same update the Void Start does not take effect.

The problem is with my Chess Pieces. I have a parent class for all pieces called Pices.cs and a bunch of child classes for the specific piece. The Pices.cs class has a char inherited and updated with Void Start by the other piece classes. The default is 'F' and then in Void start in the King class it will be updated to 'K', in Void start in queen class it will be updated to 'Q', and so on...

An example of the problem in action during one update of the game state:

if I have two ponds which is able to take the enemy queen. I would like to take the enemy queen with my first pond, reverse the move and Instantiate the queen back, then destroy the queen with my other pond, reverse the move and Instantiate the queen back, the do something totally different. But when the queen gets instantiated the second time doing this update the identification char is 'F' and not 'Q' as I wish.

The Relevant Code and notes:

All movement in-game is handled by Board_Manager.cs

Droning.cs = Queen pice in my language

Reverse move(){...} reset the game stage to start and dose all moves again except for the last one

Endgame(){...} Destroy all pice game objects and Instantiate them on the start position

The current move notation is as follows: 
1. Piece Letter, 2. from x, 3. from y, 4. to x, 5. to y, 6. Death piece letter (if no pice died then -)

[Picture of relevant pices.cs code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cll1d.png)

[Picture of relevant Queen.cs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGHFd.png)

[Picture of ReversMove() in Board_Manager.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM7lA.png)

[Picture of MiniMax base algorithem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON1Ns.png)

[Print of resulting move notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPEu6.png)

I know this is a bit convoluted but I hope some of you understand the problem and can help me out here. This is part of my examination so I would really like to get this fixed (:

Comment: OK, SO frowns upon pictures of code, as no ones gonna type all that in.. But your subject "Unity void start does not run multiple times" no, no it doesnt it runs once per instance....  Making an undo command does tend to mean you have to make note of all the settings that were impacted, eg, if you destroy something, make note of all the settings on it so you can put it back.. etc

Comment: I have managed to find a workaround by checking for the class type instead of the identification char. The problem therefor dose not matter to this project in this example anymore. 
and BugFinder thanks for the answer.
even thoug it is not ass ergent right now i would still like to learn. How would you go about saving some kind of note on all the setting in an easy and butifule way?

Comment: Could you please post your code as text using code formatting? (If you still need help.) It makes helping much easier.